# VBA code to lock only user selected (Highlighted) cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how can i one use VBA/macros to lock certain excel cells that are selected/highlighted by the user.

The code im using right now is locking the entire sheet.

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Cells.Select
Selection.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform any actions on the selected cell(s) every time a new selection occurs, you should rely on the code being triggered when this happens:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Selection.Locked = True

End Sub
```

This inside the file with the code for the given sheet; that is, if you want to consider `Sheet1`, the file where you have to write this code is: `Microsoft Excel Objects/Sheet1 (Sheet1)`.

UPDATE AFTER YOUR COMMENT

```
Sub Button1_Click()
      Selection.Locked = True
End Sub
```

This code locks all the cells selected when the `Button1` is clicked.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I dont want the action to be triggered every time some cells are selected. I only want them to run when they select the cells and run the macro.

Comment: Then rely on Selection. Selection means all the cells currently selected, that is, the ones selected when you run the macro.

Comment: I have updated my code. The idea is simple: Selection holds the information you want, thus use it in the moment you need (every time, when a function is called, when a button is clicked, etc.). BUT don't select any cells from the code (don't do Cells.Select) because would alter this variable, let the user perform the selection.

Comment: Well, i did use the same command in the original code that i posted. It locks the entire sheet instead of only the highlighted ones.

Comment: When you do Cells.Select you select the whole sheet, thus delete this line and let the user do the selection. Also bear in mind that the cells might be locked by default and thus you should unlock them right at the start. The idea is really simple: Selection holds the currently-selected range; it can be selected by the user or by the code (by relying on Range.Select).

Comment: That did it. I removed the "Cells.Select" from the original code. Thank you so much for the help. I wish i could up vote too, but i dont have enough rep yet. I accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: As said in my last comment, the cells might be locked by default. Selection.Locked = True just locks the selection; if you have deleted the part Cells.Select, the selection is what the user has selected (most likely a cell). If you want to make sure that all the cells are unlocked do it by code (cells.select selection.locked = false right at the start). But I insist: the way to accomplish what you want (a pretty reliable way and actually the only one you have) is relying on Selection.Locked = True.

Comment: Thanks, don't worry this. The only important thing is that you have got the help you needed.